# Hover color of an SVG

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface

Im trying to change the color/fill of an SVG in my page (react.js app), i use it in this format

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="35" height="24" viewBox="0 0 28.013 32">
  <path id="Contact" d="M707.882-71.775a13.4,13.4,0,0,1,3.838,2.054,13.6,13.6,0,0,1,2.908,3.055,13.894,13.894,0,0,1,1.836,3.8,14.41,14.41,0,0,1,.641,4.3h-2a12.271,12.271,0,0,0-.914-4.759,11.623,11.623,0,0,0-2.525-3.8,11.66,11.66,0,0,0-3.806-2.524,12.288,12.288,0,0,0-4.76-.913,12.2,12.2,0,0,0-3.22.421,12.168,12.168,0,0,0-2.884,1.195,11.705,11.705,0,0,0-2.423,1.86,11.7,11.7,0,0,0-1.86,2.422,12.144,12.144,0,0,0-1.2,2.884,12.183,12.183,0,0,0-.421,3.218h-2a14.045,14.045,0,0,1,.657-4.306,13.873,13.873,0,0,1,1.86-3.772,13.742,13.742,0,0,1,2.915-3.031,14.161,14.161,0,0,1,3.823-2.078,9.825,9.825,0,0,1-2.189-1.594,9.852,9.852,0,0,1-1.649-2.086,10.3,10.3,0,0,1-1.047-2.453,9.793,9.793,0,0,1-.368-2.68,9.777,9.777,0,0,1,.782-3.9,10.05,10.05,0,0,1,2.141-3.18,10.062,10.062,0,0,1,3.181-2.14,9.783,9.783,0,0,1,3.9-.78,9.786,9.786,0,0,1,3.9.781,10.072,10.072,0,0,1,3.181,2.14,10.052,10.052,0,0,1,2.141,3.18,9.776,9.776,0,0,1,.781,3.9,9.742,9.742,0,0,1-.367,2.672,10.1,10.1,0,0,1-1.047,2.437,10.33,10.33,0,0,1-1.643,2.086A9.633,9.633,0,0,1,707.882-71.775Zm-12.788-8.8a7.7,7.7,0,0,0,.634,3.109,8.155,8.155,0,0,0,1.72,2.539,8.208,8.208,0,0,0,2.54,1.719,7.685,7.685,0,0,0,3.111.633,7.684,7.684,0,0,0,3.11-.633,8.151,8.151,0,0,0,2.539-1.719,8.194,8.194,0,0,0,1.721-2.539,7.7,7.7,0,0,0,.633-3.109,7.7,7.7,0,0,0-.633-3.109,8.159,8.159,0,0,0-1.721-2.539,8.171,8.171,0,0,0-2.539-1.719,7.7,7.7,0,0,0-3.11-.633,7.7,7.7,0,0,0-3.111.633,8.157,8.157,0,0,0-2.54,1.719,8.192,8.192,0,0,0-1.72,2.539,7.7,7.7,0,0,0-.634,3.109" transform="translate(-689.092 90.571)" fill="#f5f5f5" onhover:/>
</svg>
```

it is imported into the following navbar.js file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavbarData } from "./NavbarData";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import "./Navbar.css";
import Hamburger from "./Icons/Hamburger.svg";
import closeIcon from "./Icons/Close.svg";
import "./Icons/p_logo_color.png";
import Profiles from "./Icons/Profiles.svg";
import Persona from "./Icons/Persona.svg";

function Navbar() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
  const [pageName, setPageName] = useState('Monitoring Overview');
  const location = useLocation();

  const getPageTitleByUrl = (path) => {
    NavbarData.filter((navItem) => {
      if(navItem.path === path) {
        setPageName(navItem.title);
      }
    } )

  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if(location.pathname) {
      getPageTitleByUrl(location.pathname);
    }
  }, [location] ); 
  

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "undefined" }}>
        <div className="navbar">
          <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
             <img src={Hamburger} alt="hamburger" onClick={showSidebar} />
          </Link>
          <div className="pageTitle"><h1>{pageName}</h1></div>
          <div><img className="userIcon" src={Persona} alt="persona" /> </div>
          <div className="userButton">User123#</div>
          <div className="logout-button">Log Out</div>
        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
          <ul className="nav-menu-items" onClick={showSidebar}>
            <li className="navbar-toggle">
              <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
              <img src={closeIcon} alt=''/>
              </Link>
            </li>
            {NavbarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
        
                    <span className="navbutton-text" ><span className="navbutton-icon">{item.icon}</span>{item.title}</span>
                    
                    
                  </Link>
                  
                </li>
                
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

and this is the CSS of the icon's

```
.userIcon:hover{
    margin-left: 830px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    fill: #39B2A1;
    

}
```

my question is: how can i overwrite the fill i have in the original SVG file dynamically (On hover specifically)

Thanks in advance

I tried using normal CSS on the  to change the color/fill like i did with the other text .

Comment: You should first remove **onhover:** from svg path, then see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a woking example on how to change the svg color on hover.
You were already close. Hope this helps.

```css
svg:hover {
  fill: red;
}

svg.orange:hover { 
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100" height="100" x="50" y="50" />
</svg>

<svg class="orange" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100" height="100" x="50" y="50" />
</svg>
```